# nth-of-type when filtering out content

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
.user:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color:red;
}
.hideMe {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="user hideMe">Test</div>
  <div class="user hideMe">Test</div>
  <div class="user">Test</div>
  <div class="user">Test</div>
  <div class="user ">Test</div>
  <div class="user hideMe">Test</div>
  <div class="user">Test</div>
</div>
```

I have a list of users that gets filtered at times. The filtering adds a "hideMe" class to the element. The Elements have every odd user as a light grey background and every even one has a white background. Because the filter might hide a white background it makes 2 grey backgrounds happen together. Here is how it looks.
Is there any simple CSS solution to this issue?
Thanks

[image]

Here is the issue:

[image]

and here is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the HTML to the question, instead of a screen shot of the code?

Comment: I added the code in. Nothing too special

Comment: Yeah, but now we don't have to type it to help you :)